# Rounding Date with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

Can anyone explain why we get this output after rounding:

```sql
    ROUND(TO_DATE ('22-AUG-03`), 'DDD')
```

Result: `22-AUG-03`

```sql
    ROUND(TO_DATE ('22-AUG-03`), 'DAY')
```

Result: `24-AUG-03`

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/datetime-functions/oracle-round(date)-function.php

Comment: **CAUTION**: rounding dates with the `'DAY'` format model argument rounds to the nearest beginning of the week. The "beginning of the week" **depends on the then-current setting** of the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter; so the query may give different results depending on who runs the query (and, more importantly, where they are located).

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058) that the 'DDD' format will round to the nearest day and 'DAY' will round to the beginning of the week.

```
DDD, DD, J  Day (of the year/of the month/Julian day) 
DAY, DY, D  Closest Start of the Week
```

Comment: for future reference please remember that Start of the Week is determined by **NLS settings**. Consequently in many territories it is not Sunday. (Although that's what the Americans use, and, as Oracle is American, American settings are the default.)